# Forcing reinstallation when necessary

Tags: .net, wix, installation, wix3.6

**Fact**
It's possible remove previous version and install newer with WiX using something like this:

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version is already installed."/>
```

**Complication**
With same valid version (Example 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1, the 4th part it's not considered as a diferent version) the program don't uninstall the previous version.

**Question Goal**
How force program reinstall the same valid version. I mean, uninstall the previous application first and then install current version in msi file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [AllowSameVersionUpgrades](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_majorupgrade.htm) attribute your installer will perform an upgrade when only the revision has changed.

```
<MajorUpgrade
  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" 
  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version is already installed."/>
```